# How to cake bake for tables with no primary key, but only foreign keys in cakephp 4

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm generating cake bake templates from tables that do not have a primary key, but have foreign keys.

The cake bake cannot generate the template for the views because there are no primary keys in the table.

Is there a way to generate templates, forcing the cake bake to continue the generation?

```
.\cake bake template APPLICATION_LOGS
```

result:

```
Cannot generate views for models with no primary key. Command aborted
```

Comment: My understanding is that it always needs a primary key. Can you just add an autoincrement id field?

Comment: @GregSchmidt, It is not an option to add autoincrement id in the table, because the lead developer created it that way, so i dont have a choice but to stick with the structure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that at least at one point, Cake required that all tables, including join tables, have a primary key. Not just for baking, but for `->link()` and `->unlink()` operations, and maybe other things as well (cascading deletes seem like an obvious one). I haven't migrated to v4 yet, so maybe that's not the case any more.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked and cakephp not provide the bake without primary key for templates you can create the tables files from below command

```
bin/cake bake model test
```

But, for the templates they required primary key.
I have one solution like you can add the temporary primary key and bake the template then you can remove the primary key and again bake the tables so in this way you can resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the work around solution, and because this table is just an association linking to the parent table.

`bin\cake bake model ApplicationLogs --table application_log --no-associations`

add the associations in the ApplicationLogsTable manually
create the template files manually